# Reasons for continuity of function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity

I am supposed to determine the continuity of following function:

$$f:(x-1)^{2}+2$$

I know that domain of the function are real numbers and when I sketch it, I can see that it is continous. But I do not know how to explain it, or in better words to prove it.

Can anyone help me? 
I cannot use anything, which is connected with limits.

Comment: Do you have a theorem that tells you that products, sums and differences of continuous functions are continuous?

Comment: @user328442 no, just that composition of two continuous functions is continous function.. but can you explain it?

Comment: Compositions will work as well. Try $g(x) = x-1$ and $h(x) = x^2$. That much will get you $(h \circ g)(x) = (x-1)^2$ as continuous (perhaps you will need to show that each of this is continuous if you have never done so already). From there, add the constant $2$ to the composite function and it is very easy to demonstrate the resulting sum as continuous.

Comment: But a direct approach works just fine as well

Comment: @user328442 thanks, what do you mean by direct approach?

Comment: See Kavi Rama Murthy answer to see what I mean by a direct approach.

Comment: @user328442 thanks a lot, you really help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|f (x)-f(x_0)|= |x-x_0|(|x+x_0-2| \leq |x-x_0|(|x-x_0|+2+2|x_0|) <\epsilon $ if $|x-x_0| <\min \{1, \frac {\epsilon} {3+2|x_0|}\}$.